# ng-show on click in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm having trouble getting ng-show to work correctly when a user clicks an icon. The behaviour should be as follows: The parent div loads and shows some content. When the user clicks the play icon, the contents of the div become hidden. However, right now it doesn't seem to be working. See code below:

```
<div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8 center-block" ng-show="showMe = true">

        <div class="play">
            <span class="icon_play" ng-click="showMe=false"></span>
        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This is how ng-show works https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
<div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8 center-block" ng-show="showMe" ng-init="showMe = true">
```

Answer (score 2):

This syntax is incorrect:

```
ng-show="showMe = true"
```

When evaluated, it assigns true to the field 'showMe'.

You should put instead:

```
ng-show="showMe"
```

This won't fix your problem because the field 'showMe' is not initialized to true.

So you could invert your logic:

```
<div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8 center-block" ng-show="!dontShowMe">

    <div class="play">
        <span class="icon_play" ng-click="dontShowMe=true"></span>
    </div>

</div>
```

or initialize showMe in your controller code.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `showMe` to true instead of checking if it's set to `true`.

```
<div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8 center-block" ng-show="showMe">

        <div class="play">
            <span class="icon_play" ng-click="showMe=false"></span>
        </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want an expression for your ng-show, not an assignment. See the doc here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

you want something like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8 center-block" ng-show="showMe">

        <div class="play">
            <span class="icon_play" ng-click="showMe=false"></span>
        </div>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thomporter/tcVhN/